# Identificar a Area, o Controller e a Action de uma View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

Preciso criar um HtmlHelper (MVC 4, C#) que identifique e informe qual é a Area, Controller e Action de uma View. Não estou conseguindo nada.

Como isso pode ser feito?
Existe algum função ou método que já faça isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em um projeto básico de MVC você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var e = this.RouteData.Values;

        string controllerName = (string)e["controller"];
        string actionName = (string)e["action"];

        return View();
    }
}
```

Caso queira pegar esses valores de modo genérico (especialmente nos filtros), é possível acessar a RouteData atráves do método OnActionExecuting (existem outros que provém isto também):

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var routeData = filterContext.RouteData; // aqui também

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

**Complemento**: Coletando dados através de uma extensão

Crie uma classe dentro da pasta ~/Extensions/ com o nome LocationHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebTest.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dados sobre a localização obtido da rota atual
    /// </summary>
    public class LocationData
    {
        public string ActionName { get; set; }

        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class LocationHelper
    {
        public static LocationData GetLocationData<TModel>(this WebViewPage<TModel> page)
        {
            // TODO: validate page, ViewContext, RouteData, Values
            //      for:
            //          not null, contain values
            return new LocationData()
            {
                ActionName = (string)page.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"],
                ControllerName = (string)page.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
                // TODO: get area name
            };
        }
    }
}
```

referencie ela na View e utilize o método estático como feito à seguir:

```
@using WebTest.Extensions
<div>
    <label>Action Name: </label>
    <output>@this.GetLocationData().ActionName</output>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Controller Name: </label>
    <output>@this.GetLocationData().ControllerName</output>
</div>
```

Após isso execute a página, observe os resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há algumas coisas à serem feitas:

- Validações nessa extensão, como valores nulos e também adicionar o retorno da Área.

Pontos extras:

- Não fiz este exemplo como um 'Helper' verdadeiro do ASP.NET Mvc... para criá-los você precisa adicionar a pasta do ASP.NET chamada `App_Code` (pode fazer isso no menu de contexto do projeto) e após isso com o botão direito nesta pasta você pode adicionar um Helper (ele cria um código base para você), a maneira de usar é absolutamente a mesma, a diferença é que este helper é mais voltado à sintaxe Razor.

Comment: esqueci do detalhe do HtmlHelper... dentro da View chame o helper passando @ViewContext.RouteData (mesma coisa)

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar como eu faço pra usar esse helper, estou começando agora no MVC

Comment: adicionei como complemento da resposta, espero que ajude :)

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo :D

Comment: Como identificar a area?